# ¿Como actualizar la lista al ejecutar las funciones del CRUD?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Tengo un CRUD en el panel de administración que consta de una tabla que representa los datos de la bbdd y cada acción (borrar, editar y crear) abre un modal que es un componente a parte donde esta cada función definida. Lo que desearía y no logro es que al ejecutar una acción del CRUD, se vean los cambios al momento, por ahora para verlos e de recargar la pagina. Al estar en diferentes componentes, no se como actualizar la tabla. Si alguien puede aportar alguna idea...Pongo el código del modal de borrado y la tabla.

```
interface Props {
    showModalDelete: {
        show: boolean;
        id: number;
    },
    closeModalDelete: () => void         
}

export const ModalDeleteNotifications: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModalDelete, closeModalDelete, }) => {


    const deleteNotification = () => {
        closeModalDelete()
        deleteById(showModalDelete.id).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
           
            toast.success('Notificación borrada');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            
            throw error;
        });
    }



    return(

        <>
        {showModalDelete.show ?
                      
           <>
       
           <div id="defaultModal" aria-hidden="true" className="fixed top-0 z-40 inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity "></div>

           <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50 overflow-y-auto ">
               <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 sm:items-center sm:p-0">
                   <CardBox className="w-full max-w-lg">
                       {/* Modal header */}
                       <div className="flex justify-between items-start py-4 rounded-t border-b dark:border-gray-600 mb-4 px-6">
                           <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Borrar ventaja</h3>
                           <button type="button" className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" onClick={closeModalDelete}>
                               <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                   <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clipRule="evenodd"></path>
                               </svg>
                               <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                           </button>
                       </div>
                       {/* Modal body */}
                       <div className="p-6 space-y-6">
                       
                                   <div>
                                       <p className="text-neutral-600">¿Estas seguro de eliminar esta notificación? Si es así pulsa sobre el botón Aceptar.</p>
                                   </div>
                                   

                                   <BaseDivider />

                                   <BaseButtons>
                                       <BaseButton onClick={()=>deleteNotification()}  color="icofcv" label="Aceptar" />
                                       <BaseButton type="reset" color="icofcv" outline  onClick={closeModalDelete} label="Cancelar" />
                                   </BaseButtons>
                       </div>
                   </CardBox>
               </div>
           </div>
       
       </>
      
    
      :null
    }
   </>
    )
}

///tabla
nst TableNotifications = () => {

    const [notificationList, setNotificationList] = useState<Notification[]>([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [currentPageNotification, setCurrentPageNotification] = useState(0);
    const [viewMoreNotificationDataDisabled, setViewMoreNotificationDataDisabled] = useState(false);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [showModalDelete, setShowModalDelete] = useState({show:false, id: -1});
    const [showModalEdit, setShowModalEdit] = useState({show:false, id: -1, title: '', body: '', actionType: '', actionTarget: ''});

    const openModalDelete = id => setShowModalDelete({show:true, id});
    const closeModalDelete = () => setShowModalDelete({show:false, id: -1});

    const openModalEdit = (id, title, body, actionType, actionTarget) => setShowModalEdit({show:true, id, title, body, actionType, actionTarget});
    const closeModalEdit = () => setShowModalEdit({show:false, id: -1, title: '', body: '', actionType: '', actionTarget: ''});

   
    const fetchNotificationPaginated = async (filter) => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        getNotificationPaginated(filter)
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(`response.length: ${response.length}`);
            if (response.length > getItemsPerPage()) {
                response.pop();
                setViewMoreNotificationDataDisabled(false);

            } else {                
                setViewMoreNotificationDataDisabled(true);
            }

            let list:Notification[] = [];
            if (filter.page == 0) {
                list = response;
            } else {
                list = [...notificationList, ...response];
            }
            setNotificationList(list);
            setIsLoading(false)
            console.log(list);
        }).catch((error)  => {
            console.error(error);
            setIsLoading(false)
            throw error;
        });
    }

    
    const handleShowMoreData = () => {
        setCurrentPageNotification(currentPageNotification + 1);
        
        const filter = {
            page: currentPageNotification + 1,
           
        };

        fetchNotificationPaginated(filter);
    }
  

    useEffect(() => {
       
      const filter = {
        page: 0,
        order: 'id desc'
    };

    fetchNotificationPaginated(filter)

    }, []);


  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Creado</th>
            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Titulo</th>
            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Descripción</th>
            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Tipo de acción</th>
            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Sección</th>
            <th className="text-xs text-neutral-800">Estado</th>
            <th />
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      
          {notificationList.map((notification) => (
            <tr key={notification.id}>
              {/*<td className="border-b-0 lg:w-6 before:hidden">
                <UserAvatar username={client.name} className="w-24 h-24 mx-auto lg:w-6 lg:h-6" />
              </td>*/}
               <td data-label="Created" className="lg:w-40 whitespace-nowrap">
                <small className="text-teal-500 dark:text-slate-400">{notification.id}</small>
              </td>
              <td data-label="Title" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{notification.title}</td> 
              <td data-label="description" className="text-xs text-neutral-800">{notification.body}</td>           
              <td data-label="actionType" className="lg:w-40 text-xs text-neutral-800">{notification.actionType}</td>
              <td data-label="section" className="lg:w-60 text-xs text-neutral-800">{notification.actionTarget}</td>
              {notification.status === 1 ?
              <td data-label="state" className="text-xs text-sky-500 font-medium">ENVIADO</td>
              :
              <td data-label="state" className="text-xs text-sky-500 font-medium">NO ENVIADO</td>
                }
              <td className="before:hidden lg:w-1 whitespace-nowrap">
                <div className="justify-start lg:justify-end whitespace-nowrap" >
                {notification.status === 0 ?
                  <BaseButton onClick={() =>openModalEdit(notification.id, notification.title, notification.body, notification.actionType, notification.actionTarget)} icon={mdiPencil} small color="tableIcofcv" className="mx-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-teal-600 text-teal-600 hover:text-white border-0"/>
                  :<div></div>
                }
                  <BaseButton  onClick={()=> openModalDelete(notification.id)}  icon={mdiTrashCan} color="tableIcofcvDanger" small className="mx-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-red-500 text-red-500 hover:text-white border-0"/>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
     
      <div className="p-3 lg:px-6 border-t border-gray-100 dark:border-slate-800">
        
         {viewMoreNotificationDataDisabled === false ?
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-end mx-3">
                        <button className="bg-transparent text-teal-600 text-sm active:bg-teal-700 py-2 outline-none focus:outline-none rounded underline" type="button" onClick={handleShowMoreData}>Ver más</button>
                    </div>
                    :
                    <div></div>
                }
      </div>
      {isLoading && <Loader />}
      <ModalEditNotification showModalEdit={showModalEdit} closeModalEdit={closeModalEdit } />
      <ModalDeleteNotifications  showModalDelete={showModalDelete} closeModalDelete={closeModalDelete }  />
    </>
  )
}

export default TableNotifications
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para actualizar la tabla al ejecutar una acción del CRUD, una opción sería pasar una función como propiedad desde el componente padre (que contiene la tabla) al componente del modal. Esta función podría encargarse de actualizar los datos de la tabla cada vez que se ejecute una acción del CRUD.

Por ejemplo, en el componente padre, podrías definir una función updateData que se encargue de obtener los nuevos datos de la base de datos y actualizar el estado de la tabla con ellos. Luego, podrías pasar esta función como propiedad al componente del modal:

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  function updateData() {
    // Obtener los nuevos datos de la base de datos y actualizar el estado de la tabla
    fetchData().then(newData => setData(newData));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Table data={data} />
      <ModalDeleteNotifications updateData={updateData} />
    </>
  );
}
En el componente del modal, podrías llamar a la función updateData después de ejecutar la acción del CRUD:

Copy code
interface Props {
  showModalDelete: {
    show: boolean;
    id: number;
  },
  closeModalDelete: () => void,
  updateData: () => void
}

export const ModalDeleteNotifications: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModalDelete, closeModalDelete, updateData }) => {
  const deleteNotification = () => {
    closeModalDelete();
    deleteById(showModalDelete.id).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);

      toast.success('Notificación borrada');
      // Llamar a la función updateData después de borrar la notificación
      updateData();
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);

      throw error;
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

De esta manera, cada vez que se ejecute una acción del CRUD, se actualizará la tabla con los nuevos datos de la base de datos.

Comment: gracias Mario, me ha servido de mucho porque no sabia por donde empezar, al final e modificado un poco la función porque solo necesitaba actualizar la tabla de esta manera , function updateTable() {
           
      const filter = {
        page: 0,
        order: 'id desc'
    };
      
      fetchNotificationPaginated(filter);
}

Comment: gracias a ti e podido saber como pasar la función de un componente a otro, mil gracias.

Comment: de nada amigo, espero te haya sido de sabiduria mi ayuda